# When overwriting an existing backend system.xml how do I hide a field?

Tags: admin, backend, overrides, system.xml

I'm working on making a small alteration to an existing `community` third party extension.  The extension provides a backend admin field for a black-list of attributes, and I'm working to invert it to be a white-list.

All other logic will remain the same, so I've opted to build a small `local` extension with rewrites for only the relevant changes.

In `system.xml` I've found the black-list field, and am able to override its settings from my extension.  However, how would I go about completely removing the field?

In short, I'd like to:

- Hide a field named `<black_list>` from the `community\thirdparty\extension\etc\system.xml` config
- Substitute it with a `<white_list>` field from `local\mynamespace\myextenion\etc\system.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it the same order number/id. If your extension is loaded after the other one you might be lucky to override it.

In general you can override everything from the local folder or with the right observer/event.

Comment: I have it working, provided that I override their existing `<black_list>` field.  Does that mean that I can't remove existing fields from the UI--just alter their configuration?

Comment: @STW That's correct, there's no official mechanism for removing a field.